# Adding information to bibitems

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

For a lecture note/book project I have to following problem: I have an extensive list of references processed by bibtex as usual, the entries coming from a large collection of bib-files. Now since the whole project is ment for students, I would like to add some recommendations for particular references like:

> This is a standard text book where every student will have to take a look,
>   for this course Chap~3 and Chap~4 are most important.

Of course, I can add lines like that directly as a "note" into the bib-files, but I do not want to spoil my bib-file collection with notes like that which I never will need again (imagine this kind of note appears in a journal article by accident).

So the question is: can I modify the behaviour of the bibitem command such that I have an additonal command like `\bibnote{key}{text}` somewhere in my main file, taking the key of the bibentry and adds some text at the end of it, maybe as a separate paragraph. Ideally, it would write things directly to the bbl-file automatically.

Comment: Make a back-up of your bib file?

Comment: @percuße hehe, sure that is one option. But the point is that I wanted the bibfiles to be kept sync with the master copy. Perhaps I will just do it this way though...

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution that does not require changing the style file. It uses the `datatool` package to collect the notes. Note also that there are versions for natbib and without natbib, choose what fits your demands.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

%% database for personal temporary notes
\DTLnewdb{bibnotes}

%% command for notes
\def\bibnote#1#2{%
  \DTLnewrow{bibnotes}
  \DTLnewdbentry{bibnotes}{mylabel}{#1}
  \DTLnewdbentry{bibnotes}{mynote}{#2}
}

%% patching the output
\makeatletter
%% if natbib is loaded
\patchcmd{\@lbibitem}%
  {\item[\hfil\NAT@anchor{#2}{\NAT@num}]}%
  {%
    \item[\hfil\NAT@anchor{#2}{\NAT@num}]%
    \DTLforeach[\DTLiseq{\mylabel}{#2}]{bibnotes}{\mylabel=mylabel,\mynote=mynote}{\textit{\mynote}}
  }{}{\message{^^JPatching failed^^J}}%

%% if natbib is not loaded
% \patchcmd{\@lbibitem}%
%   {\item[\@biblabel {#1}\hfill ]}%
%   {%
%     \item[\@biblabel {#1}\hfill ]%
%     \DTLforeach[\DTLiseq{\mylabel}{#2}]{bibnotes}{\mylabel=mylabel,\mynote=mynote}{\textit{\mynote}}
%   }{}{\message{^^JPatching failed^^J}}%
% \patchcmd{\@bibitem}%
%   {\item}%
%   {%
%     \item%
%     \DTLforeach[\DTLiseq{\mylabel}{#1}]{bibnotes}{\mylabel=mylabel,\mynote=mynote}{\textit{\mynote}}
%   }{}{\message{^^JPatching failed^^J}}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\cite{GhJaEn02,MeGa05,MuBeBoRo99}

\bibnote{GhJaEn02}{This is important }
\bibnote{GhJaEn02}{to understand chickens!}
\bibnote{MeGa05}{This is about penguins:}
\bibnote{MuBeBoRo99}{Cheese!}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If the combination of `biblatex+biber` is an option you can use the mapping feature to add information to a bibentry. This can be done, by using

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps{
    \map{
      \step[fieldset=entrykey, fieldvalue={<entryke>}]
      \step[fieldset=note, fieldvalue={text for <entrykey>}]
    }
  }
}
```

and use a map for every reference for which you want to add the note.

Or an alternative is to introduce a new field, let us say, `notesonlyformystudent` (and use such a field in the `.bib` file).

```
\begin{filecontents}{biblatex-dm.cfg}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{notesonlyformystudents}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{notesonlyformystudents}
\end{filecontents}
```

and

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{notesonlyformystudents}{#1}
\renewbibmacro{finentry}{\finentry\par\printfield{notesonlyformystudents}}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping to see a good old bibtex solution, but maybe this is now a good reason to switch to the 21st century ;)

Comment: @StefanWaldmann I have added a bibtex solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that can be used in conjunction with `biblatex` and `bibtex`

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\bibnote}[2]{\@namedef{#1note}{#2}}
\makeatother
```

For `biblatex` one has to redefine the `finentry` biblatex macro

```
\renewbibmacro{finentry}{\finentry\par\csname \thefield{entrykey}note\endcsname\finentry}
```

For `bibtex` one has to modify the `.bst` bibliographic style, in particular, redefine the `fin.entry` function as follows:

```
FUNCTION {fin.entry}
{ add.period$
  write$
  newline$
  "\par\csname " write$
  cite$ write$
  "note\endcsname" write$
  newline$
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is by natbib. Please read the part of the documentation attached as image. Merge need to be invoked with natbib.

[image]